# Проставление значений по условию в другом столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть таблица:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
    ...                          "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
    ...                    "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
    ...                          "one", "one", "two", "two"],
    ...                    "C": ["2017", "2017", "2018", "2017",
    ...                          "2018", "2017", "2018", "2017",
    ...                          "2017"],
    ...                    "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
```

Необходимо проставить в столбец E значения 'Yes' если в строке A 'foo' и 'No' если 'bar'

Пытаюсь итерироваться по столбцу следующим образом:

```
for x in df['A']:
    if 'foo' in x:
        df'['E'] = 'Yes'
```

Но в таком виде, как я понял будет проставлено на весь столбец 'E' одно значение. Как правильно это сделать?

Т.е нужно не просто при совпадении значения, а при вхождении некоего объекта в строку выполнить условие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.map(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
In [178]: df['E'] = df['A'].map({'foo':'Yes','bar':'No'})
```

Чтобы проверить по подстроке:

```
In [183]: df['E'] = np.where(df['A'].str.contains('fo'), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Результат:

```
In [184]: df
Out[184]:
     A    B     C  D    E
0  foo  one  2017  1  Yes
1  foo  one  2017  2  Yes
2  foo  one  2018  2  Yes
3  foo  two  2017  3  Yes
4  foo  two  2018  3  Yes
5  bar  one  2017  4   No
6  bar  one  2018  5   No
7  bar  two  2017  6   No
8  bar  two  2017  7   No
```

Comment: А если будет не 'foo', а 'fo', т.е нужно определить вхождение в строку.

Comment: Спасибо. Так помогло. А если делать без numpy. Например у меня известно только x значение без y, или сложное условие с несколькими if. как итерироваться в таком случае и проверять условие

Comment: @Gremlin, лучше задайте новый вопрос с конкретным примером и желательно привести в примере различные сложные варианты, которые могут встретиться в ваших реальных данных. Ответ может сильно различаться в зависимости от того что вы хотите получить на выходе